# Is there a way to freeze TODAY for when it was written to a cell in Google Sheets?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, timestamp

Using `today()`, I have a cell populate with the current date when an adjacent cell is filled. Unfortunately, when tomorrow rolls around, yesterday's date, from tomorrow's perspective, will be the wrong date.

Is there a way to freeze `today()` as the day it was written and not the current date?

Note: there are thousands of these cells, so doing <kbd>`Cmd`</kbd> + <kbd>`;`</kbd> does not solve this issue. It needs to be a formula that can be copied to those thousands of cells.

Comment: No, you will need to use google-script to write code to do what you want.  A formula is "live".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

possible only with script:

```
function onEdit(e) {
var s = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
if( s.getName() == "Sheet3" ) { 
var r = s.getActiveCell();
if( r.getColumn() == 13 ) { 
  var nextCell = r.offset(0, 9);
  var newDate = Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), 
  "GMT+8", "MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss");
  nextCell.setValue(newDate);
}}}
```

- **`"Sheet3"`** = sheet name
- **`r.getColumn() == 13`** = column **M** / 13th column
- **`r.offset(0, 9)`** = offset timestamp 9 columns to the right on the same row eg column **V**
- **`"GMT+8"`** = timezone
- **`"MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss"`** = date and time format