# How to prevent the NOW() function in google sheet to update everytime when there is a change in the cells in the sheet?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, timestamp

I want to print the timestamp in column C when the status shows "Complete". However, when I use the `NOW()` function, it will keep updating the cells when there is a change in other cells. My formula in Cell `C4` is `=IF(B4="Complete",NOW(),"")`. This formula are not able to solve the problem of auto-updating. May I know is there anyway to handle this situation? If the Google App Script is the only way (hopefully not), how should I code it (first time deal with JavaScript)?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Google Sheets there is no way to stop `NOW()` from recalculating other than replace it by it's value.

The best way to achieve what you are looking for is to use Google Apps Script, more specifically you will have to use an on edit trigger. Below is an example based on what is shown in the screenshot included in the question:

```
function onEdit(e){
  if(e.range.columnStart === 2 && e.range.rowStart >= 4 && e.value === 'Complete'){
     e.range.offset(0,1).setValue(new Date());
  }
}
```

Please read [Extending Google Sheets with Apps Script](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/sheets). This is a very brief guide to get started with using Google Apps Script with Google Sheets and will point you to the resources to learn the basics of JavaScript.

NOTE: JavaScript and Java are two different programming languages.

Related

- [Automatic timestamp when a cell is filled out](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11458470/1595451)
- [How to automatically add a timestamp in google spreadsheet](https://stackoverflow.com/q/26374359/1595451)
- [Is there a way to freeze TODAY for when it was written to a cell in Google Sheets?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/56742124/1595451)

Comment: Thanks Ruben, after I replace `e.range.columnStart === 3` to `e.range.columnStart ==2`, it works perfectly :)

Comment: Hi Ruben, I tried to use the code written by you, but I realized that after I implement the code inside my google sheet, when I clear some value in a cell, there will be some other values been cleared as well, this is just a simple execution to clear the content in a cell but not sure why it affect other cell as well. This is quite weird and I couldn't find out what is the reason, do you have any idea?

Comment: That is not related with the code in the answer. I suggest you to post a new question.

Answer (score 0):

Your formula is correct but need to change little things. You should write this formula in this way if(C4,C4,if($B4="Complete",NOW(),"")).  and go to the file menu then spredsheet settings then calculation and then recalculation and at last its change to "On Change".

Answer (score 0):

I was able to figure out how to keep the timestamp from changing by using a formula that someone had shared with me a while back. I haven't figured out how to get it to work though using ARRAYFORMULA, but it does work if you just drag down the formula to all the cells in Column B that you want it to work for. You can test it out by typing in "Complete", starting in A5, and you'll see that it works. Here's the formula I used...

```
=if(A5="Complete",lambda(x,x)(now()),)
```

[Here's a link to make a copy of the Google Sheet to test it out.](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1heVL2ggAncRHtEYKGkiLAKL2DDfH8n050SH2sRHFnAs/copy)

One other thing...if you'd like this to work where it provides the timestamp when a box is checked, you can use this formula, and it will freeze the timestamp.

```
=if(A5,lambda(x,x)(now()),)
```

Don't forget to drag down the formula to all cells in the column where you want the timestamp to appear.

Comment: Doesn't work. Recalculates with refresh (use time and you will see). the function is reevaluated with each refresh...

Comment: @wgw it's interesting...it actually only changes after one refresh. After that, it remains static and doesn't change.